# Is correct this interpretation about a git diff HEAD message?

Tags: git, github, git-diff

I'm doing a git tutorial and I would like someone tells me if my interpretation of this message is correct:

```
$ git diff HEAD

diff --git a/octocat.txt b/octocat.txt
index 7d8d808..e725ef6 100644
--- a/octocat.txt           
+++ b/octocat.txt           
@@ -1 +1 @@                 
-A Tale of Two Octocats
+[mA Tale of Two Octocats and an Octodog
```

If I understood well, the command tells you what differences are between your last commit and the present moment, right?.

```
diff --git a/octocat.txt b/octocat.txt
```

This line tells you that octocat.txt has been modified. What I don't know here it's what `a/` and `b/` mean.

```
--- a/octocat.txt           
+++ b/octocat.txt
```

Line with --- it's the document before being modified and line with +++ refers to the document after being modified.

```
@@ -1 +1 @@
```

this it's a unified diff hunk identifier. Unified format it's used to display changes between files, right? I'm not native English and I want to be sure I understood it.

```
-A Tale of Two Octocats
+[mA Tale of Two Octocats and an Octodog
```

And finally, here is displayed what was deleted and what was added.

Thanks ;)

Comment: `a/` and `b/` are just there to differentiate between the old and new file, they are dummy identifiers (`diff --git file file` wouldn't make much sense). Otherwise your analysis is spot on!

Comment: yep ... not sure what the question is , since you seem right

Comment: @Noctis, I think you're right. A better question could be "Is correct this interpretation about a git diff HEAD message?". I'm going to edit it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a/` and `b/` are just there to differentiate between the old and new file, they are dummy identifiers (`diff --git file file` wouldn't make much sense). Otherwise your analysis is spot on!

From the [git diff](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) man page:

> `git diff [--options] <commit> [--] [<path>...]`
>      This form is to view the changes you have in your working tree
>      relative to the named `<commit>`. You can use `HEAD` to compare it with
>      the latest commit, or a branch name to compare with the tip of a
>      different branch.

Although, most of the time, you will be more likely to simply use `git diff` (without any arguments) to show what changes are in your working copy, but have not yet been added to the index (in other words: "have not yet been staged").

- `git diff HEAD`: shows every change to tracked files not yet committed
- `git diff`: shows changes relative to the index (i.e. not yet staged)